# Defining Symfony Services to maximize maintainability

Tags: symfony, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm working on a big domain, for which maintainability is very important.
There are these general workers called `ExcelHandler`s that implement `ExcelHandlerInterface` (more on the interface in the ideas section) and basically get an `UploadedFile` as their input, upload them wherever they want and return the read data as an associative array.  Now I have created this base class `ExcelFileHandler` which does all of these tasks for all excel files given two arguments:
 1. The Directory  to upload the file
2. the mapping of the excel columns to the indexes of the associative array.
Some `ExcelHandler`s might have to extend the `ExcelFileHandler` and do some more processing, in order to get the associative array of data.
The `UploadedFile` is always passed to the `ExcelHandler` from the controller.
Now here is the question. Given the generic structure of the `ExcelFileHandler` how should I define services for specific `ExcelHandler`s given that some only differ with the original one in the **directory** to upload the file and the **mapping** array.
My Ideas:

---

**1.** The first approach involves giving the **directory** and the **mapping** as the function arguments to `ExcelHandleInterface::handle` this will make the prototype something like `handle(UploadedFile $file, array $mapping, $dir)`, `$mapping` and `$dir` are given to the function as arguments and passed to the handler by the controllers which has the parameters as constructor injections.

---

**2.1** Defining the prototype of `handle` to be `handle(UploadedFile $file)`, this would require the `ExcelHandler`s to have knowledge of `$dir` and `$mapping`.  `$dir` will always be injected from the constructor.
**2.1.1** Foreach individual `ExcelHandler` in the application, define a separate class e.g: `UserExcelHandler`, `ProductExcelHandler`, .... Which extend the `ExcelFileHandler` and leaves us again with two choices.
**2.1.1.1** inject `$mapping` from outside.  e.g:

```
// in the child class
public function __construct($dir, $mapping){
  parent::__construct($dir, $mapping);
}
```

**2.1.1.2** define `$mapping` in the constructor of the child class.  e.g:

```
// in the child class
public function __construct($dir){
  $mapping = array(0 => 'name', 1 => 'gender');
  parent::__construct($dir, $mapping);
}
```

**2.1.2** **Not** to create a class for each separate `ExcelHandler` and instead define the `ExcelFileHandler` as an `abstract` service and decorate with the right parameters to get the concrete `ExcelHandler` Service with the desired functionality, obviously `ExcelHandlers` with custom logic must be defined seperately, and to create a uniform code base, `$mapping` will always be injected from the Container in this case.

---

In your experience, what other paths can I take  and which ones yield better results in the long term?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it seams as you've already put two separate things into one.

Uploading a file and reading it's contents are two separate concerns, which can change separately (like you said, `$directory` and `$mapping` can change case-by-case). Thus I would suggest to use separate services for uploading and reading the file.

See [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) for more information.

Furthermore, due to very similar reasons, I would not recommend base classes at all - I'd prefer composition over inheritance.

Imagine that you have 2 methods in your base class: `upload`, which stores file to a local directory, and `parse`, which reads excel file and maps columns to some data structure.

1. If you need to store file in a remote storage (for example FTP), you need to override `upload` method. Let's call this service1.
2. If you need to parse file differently, for example combining data from 2 sheets, you need to override `parse` method. Let's call this service2.
3. If you need to override both of these methods, while still being able to get service1 and service2, you're stuck, as you'll need to copy-and-paste the code. There's no easy way to use already written functionality from (1) and (2).

In comparison, if you have interface with `upload` method and interface with `parse` method, you can inject those 2 separate services where you need them as you need them. You can mix any implementations of those already available. All of them are already tested and you do not need to write any code - just to configure the services.

One more thing to mention - there is absolutely no need to create (and name) classes by their usage. Name them by their behaviour. For example, if you have `ExcelParser`, which takes `$mapping` as an argument to a constructor, no need to call it `UserExcelParser` if the code itself has nothing to do with users. If you need to parse data from several sheets, just create `SheetAwareExcelParser` etc., not `ProductExcelParser`. This way you can reuse the code. Also correct naming lets understand the code more easily.

In practice, I've seen when function or class is named by it's usage, and then it's just used in another place with no renaming, refactoring etc. These cases are really not what you're looking for.

Service names (in another words concrete objects, not classes), can of course be named by their purpose. You just configure them with any required functionality (single vs separate sheets etc.)

To summarize, I would use `2.1.2` above all other of your given options. I would inject `$dir` and `$mapping` via DI in any case, as these do not change in runtime - these are configuration.

Comment: I am actually using two other interfaces `FileUploader` and `ExcelMapper`, they do the actual work, the base `ExcelFileHandler` is what actually brings them together. and since in most `ExcelHandler`s the method `handle` wil be something like `$file = $this->uploader->upload($file, $dir); $excel = $this->excelFactory->create($file); return $this->mapper->map($excel, $this->mapping);`, I thought I would create a Base Class `ExcelFileUploader` that implements that method like that and can be overridden when needed. What do you think about Using Inheritance when using it this way?

Comment: I think it's ok to manage all those things in `ExcelFileUploader`, but I would not extend it - only inject with different instances if needed. Also, it seems that `$this->mapping` should be injected into `$this->mapper`, not passed as an argument. At least I would do it like that, as you could use the same mapper (with exactly the same configuration) in any other place if needed. Again - it's not run-time argument, but configuration, so I would put it to the service constructor.